# Request approval database model

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization

I have a question regarding an efficient way of modeling the following scenario:

We have a "Request" which can have the following states:

- pending
- approved
- rejected
- cancelled

A request is issued by a user and can be approved/rejected by one or more users (with a higher role). There are certain rules that decide to which user should the request be assigned for approval and only if all in the respective list approve it can be really approved.

I have a Request table with the necessary info, and a User table at the moment. I have to save the following info: the users that need to approve the request and how they "voted".

How can I design this in an efficient way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a table `votes` with columns `request_id`, `user_id` and `vote`.

When a new request is created, insert for each user who has to approve it one row in `votes` like (new_request_id, approver_id, 0).

When a user approves, set `vote` to 1. If a user rejects, set it to -1. This way 0 means "no vote yet".

You also could use two tables, one for votes and one for needed approvers. But I don't see a great advantage. And of course you could add a column for the timestamp of the vote if you need it.